# Akkusativ oder Nominativ und Formulierung bei einer Bestellung

Tags: article, vocabulary, definite-article

Als ich in einem Hotel war, hat mich die Kellnerin gefragt, ob ich etwas trinken möchte. Ich habe auf Englisch geantwortet:

> "A cappuccino, please"

und ich war mir nicht sicher, wie ich das auf Deutsch sagen sollte.

Wäre das

> "Ein Cappuccino, bitte" (nom.)

oder

> "Einen Cappuccino, bitte" (akk.)

Wenn man nicht "ich möchte..." sagst, verwendet man immer noch den Akkusativ?  Übrigens, ist es vielleicht besser zu sagen

> "Ich möchte gerne ein(en) Cappuccino"...?

Ist das häufiger?

Comment: Die Kellnerin fragt nach einem Akkusativobjekt, also antwortet man auch mit einem Akkusativobjekt.

Comment: Ich werde gleich die zweite Frage entfernen. Du kannst sie separat stellen oder schauen, ob sie hier beantwortet wird: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4386 https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/37881
Diese beiden Fragen sind auf Englisch, falls Du Deine Frage noch einmal auf Deutsch stellst, ist sie nach unseren Regeln kein Duplikat.

Comment: Und Anreden etc. sparen wir uns hier, auch wenn das zunächst unhöflich erscheinen mag.

Comment: I think no-one will complain if you wrongly use "ein" in this case. However, if you order two drinks of such Italian-style coffee (even more so with Espresso), a long discussion about the correct plural may start ;)

Answer (score 3):

Die Bitte

> Einen Cappuccino, bitte!

ist nichts anderes als eine [Ellipse](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse_(Linguistik)) von

> Ich hätte gern einen Cappuccino, bitte!

Daher ist *einen Cappuccino* richtigerweise Akkusativ. Allerdings gibt es auch Kontexte, in denen die Aussage

> Ein Cappuccino, bitte!

d. h. der Nominativ, richtig wäre, wie etwa in folgendem Beispiel:

> Anna wunderte sich: „Das ist doch ein Milchkaffee?“
>   
>   „Ein Cappuccino, bitte!“, wandte die Kellnerin empört ein.

Wie man erkennt, handelt es sich in diesem Beispiel nicht mehr um eine echte Bitte, sondern um Sarkasmus.

Answer (score -2):

In der deutschen Umgangssprache ist es schon fast üblich geworden, dass man oft "ein" statt "einen" sagt (wobei keine Sprecher es 100% konsequent umsetzen), z.B. "wir haben ein__ Fehler gemacht" oder "ich hab kein Bock mehr". Und das ist nicht mal wirklich stigmatisiert in informal situations, man bemerkt es nicht mal, wenn man nicht genau hinhört. [Die Tendenz ist inzwischen auch schriftlich zu beobachten.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Ein%20Cappuccino,%20bitte%22)
Aus diesem Grund kannst du als "quick und dirty hack" zu männlichen und sächlichen Nomina (nur nicht zu weiblichen!) immer "ein" sagen - and that would still be correct colloquial German. Das könnte hilfreich sein, um die Hürde der spontanen Sprachinteraktion zu überwinden, ohne zum Englischen greifen zu müssen.

Note, however, that this is just a lifehack and that it doesn't imply you don't need to know the gender of the word at all - both because it would be incorrect in written German and in more formal situations, and also because it wouldn't help anymore should you need a definite article (den oder das in Akkusativ), as in "i need that coffee and not this one". In the language mind of a native speaker the right gender still exists, even if he/she does not distinguish "ein" und "einen" in one particular sentence in one particular grammatical case and form (e.g. indefinte article in Akkusativ).
 [A related reply](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/15652/9739)

Comment: Als Muttersprachler halte ich "wir haben ein Fehler gemacht" für einen Fehler... und ich bemerke es durchaus, auch wenn ich nichts sage. Eine gültige Variante in der Umgangssprache ist "wir haben 'nen Fehler gemacht." Wenn man nicht genau hinhört, sind "ein" und "'nen" sehr ähnlich.

Comment: Da muss ich, zumindest für den südlichen Teil des deutschen Sprachraums heftig widersprechen. Bei uns im Süden (ich bin aus dem Osten Österreichs) wirft man zwar gerne den Dativ und den Akkusativ in einen Topf, und spricht Dialekte, die keinen Genitiv haben, aber Nominativ und Akkusativ werden immer strikt getrennt. Im Dialekt lautet der Nominativ *»**a** Föla«* z.B: *»**A** Föla is schnö gmocht.«* (»Ein Fehler ist schnell gemacht.«) Der Akkusativ ist aber *»**an** Föla«* z.B. *»Mia hom **an** Föla gmocht.«* (»Wir haben einen Fehler gemacht«). Die jeweils umgekehrte Variante ...

Comment: ... (*»**An** Föla is schnö gmocht.« »Mia hom **a** Föla gmocht.«*) ist falsch und wird niemals verwendet. Und was für die Standardsprache und den Dialekt gilt, gilt auch für die Umgagnssprache, die ja irgendwo zwischen Dialekt und Standard angesiedelt ist: *»Ein Fehla is schnell gmacht.« »Wia ham einen Fehla gmacht.«* Die Verkürzung *'nen* für *einen* ist dort, wo bayrische Dialekte vorherrschen (grob gesagt: Österreich und Bayern) nicht in Verwendung. Man sagt entweder *»einen«* oder *»an«*. Und der Nominativ ist immer entweder *»ein«* oder *»a«.*

Comment: @dirkt, ich glaube, es kann daran liegen, dass du es doch nicht immer bemerkst, d.h. wenn es "ich habe ein" (oder "ein'n) ausgesprochen wird und durch dein Sprachmodul im Kopf als "ich habe einen" geparsed. Bei einigen umgangssprachlichen Redewendungen wie "ich habe kein(en) Bock"  ist die "richtige" Variante kaum mehr zu hören.

Comment: @dirkt, nur ein Beispiel, neulich habe ich mir eine Tatort-Folge angeschaut, und da sagte Klaus Behrendt, ein ausgebildeter Schauspieler über 50, genau folgendes: "wir haben ein Fehler gemacht". Dabei sprach er langsam und deutlich (so dass man nicht mehr behaupten kann, dass es einfach an einer zu schnellen Aussprache lag), und das im Fernsehen. Das ist nur ein Beispiel, was mir momentan, so auf Anhieb einfällt.

Comment: @dirkt, "Wenn man nicht genau hinhört, sind "ein" und "'nen" sehr ähnlich" - genau. Bei dir wird es dann grammatikalisch richtig geparsed, aber gesprochen wird es tatsächlich oft wie "ein". Deswegen meinte ich ja, dass es nicht leicht zu bemerken ist, wie auch viele Phänomene der Umgangssprache, deren sich mitunter nicht mal Sprachwissenschaftler bewusst sind.

Comment: @Dan Ich glaube es immer noch nicht. Welche Tatort-Folge war es (vielleicht gibt es sie ja in der Mediathek?) Wo ungefähr in der Folge sagt Behrendt das? (Ich habe schon seit Jahren keinen Tatort mehr geschaut, aber was tut man nicht alles für die Linguistik...)

Comment: @dirkt, streamcloud is down so this would be rather tricky. I'll try not to forget about this, though.

Comment: https://youtu.be/jkbEgiplm7g?t=61 https://youtu.be/R36ZVoUmbzQ?t=200  https://youtu.be/h8iq-ct7E8g?t=169 wenn man es wirklich will und sich das einbildet, kann man da ein kleines bisschen längeres "n" hören, aber ich kann wetten dass es kaum messbare Sekundenbruchteile sind. 
Oder hier. Schlicht und einfach "ein" https://youtu.be/RHPGvM0s3Yc?t=576 https://youtu.be/f7WDNjH-_cY?t=333

Comment: Noch ein prachtexemplar, auch wenn etwas zu schnell. https://youtu.be/4xss7baEbQI?t=1723

Comment: https://youtu.be/AnFsQnPIMTk?t=235 "sucht man ein bestimmtes Fossil oder ein Schlüssel"  https://youtu.be/SVk6bew1htE?t=377

Comment: Ich höre: 1) einen 2) 'nen 3) ein'n Kaffe (sehr kurz, man muss genau hinhören) 4) ein Fossil, einen Schlüssel 5) 'nen Schlüssel. In der Umgangssprache wird eben abgeschliffen, daran muss man sich als Nicht-Muttersprachler erst gewöhnen. Trotzdem ist es immer "einen", nie "ein" - das ist ein Hörfehler.

Comment: Ich glaube, das kann doch daran liegen, dass du es hören *willst*, weil es grammatikalisch Sinn ergibt. Wenn ich das gezielt und mit dem Wunsch höre, kann ich mir auch einbilden, "einen" zu hören mit einem winzigsten Schwa, aber dann höre ich mir die Stelle an, wo auch grammatikalisch "ein" verwendet worden ist, und die klingen für mich 100% gleich.. Na gut, wenn ich Zeit habe, messe ich das doch mal lieber digital, um jeglichen kognitiven Verzerrungen entegegenzusteuern.

Comment: Interessant wäre auch folgender Test: Man extrahiert kurze Audiostücke mit "ein/einen", mit genug Kontext, dass man Intonation usw. hat, aber mit nicht genug Kontext, um den Fall zu bestimmen. Dann spielt man das Muttersprachlern vor, die dann "ein/einen" wählen müssen. Bis auf (3), das zugegebenermaßen extrem nahe an einem Versprecher ist (die Frau kriegt die Kurve gerade noch, mit Mühe), würde ich wetten wollen, dass Muttersprachler den Unterschied hören. Aber völlig unabhängig davon bestehe ich darauf, dass man "einen" nicht durch "ein" ersetzen kann, und dass das nicht akzeptabel ist.

Comment: https://youtu.be/AnFsQnPIMTk?t=235 ist "oder entschlüsselt die DNS-Sequenz" 

Comment: @DavidVogt weiß nicht wie es mir gerutscht ist